# Как программно измененить громкость звука в Windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-7, аудио

Как программно измененить громкость звука в Windows?

Можете написать пример?
Желательно, чтобы скомпилился  на `minGW`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел хороший пример на MSDN: [How to Use Wave Audio Volume Control APIs](http://web.archive.org/web/20100312082802/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139098), есть как получение громкости, так и установка. Данный пример дает нужный результат на версиях WIndows ниже Vista.

В Windows Vista и 7 были представлены новые API для работы с аудио, для изменения громкости глобально нужно использовать интерфейс `IAudioEndpointVolume`. Небольшой пример использования есть также в [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331828(VS.85).aspx) и на [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/233484/Change-Master-Volume-in-Visual-Cplusplus):

Comment: вот с ним и разбираюсь 
пытаюсь код транслировать в с на mingw
конкретно вот с этой строчкой парюсь
(MIXERCONTROL)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)(mlc.pamxctrl + (int)mlc.cbmxctrl * i));

Comment: М-м-м. А что непонятно?

Comment: поправил ответ

Comment: Теперь гораздо лучше. Уберу минус.

Comment: скомпилил я его без проблем вот только не работает

Comment: Как я понял программа меняет уровень звука только в приложении (у самой себя)) а не в системе

Comment: да, начиная с висты нужно использовать другие api, я обновил ответ, добавил ссылки на два примера работающих в windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Анимированое изменение звука системы Win7 C++ visual studio 10

```
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib") //extern

bool ChangeVolume(double nVolume,bool bScalar)
{

    HRESULT hr=NULL;
    bool decibels = false;
    bool scalar = false;
    double newVolume=nVolume;

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                          __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator);
    IMMDevice *defaultDevice = NULL;

    hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice);
    deviceEnumerator->Release();
    deviceEnumerator = NULL;

    IAudioEndpointVolume *endpointVolume = NULL;
    hr = defaultDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), 
         CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, (LPVOID *)&endpointVolume);
    defaultDevice->Release();
    defaultDevice = NULL;

    // -------------------------
    float currentVolume = 0;
    endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevel(&currentVolume);
    //printf("Current volume in dB is: %f\n", currentVolume);

    hr = endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&currentVolume);
    //CString strCur=L"";
    //strCur.Format(L"%f",currentVolume);
    //AfxMessageBox(strCur);

    // printf("Current volume as a scalar is: %f\n", currentVolume);
    if (bScalar==false)
    {
        hr = endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevel((float)newVolume, NULL);
    }
    else if (bScalar==true)
    {
        hr = endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar((float)newVolume, NULL);
    }
    endpointVolume->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    return FALSE;
}

float i = 0;
int main()
{

    float volume = 0;

    while(1)
    {
    i+=0.01;
    volume = (sin(i)+1)/2;

    ChangeVolume(volume,1);
    std::cout<<volume<<std::endl;
    Sleep(33);
    }
}
```

Пользователь [MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight) заметил что 
"Не нужно каждый раз вызывать CoInitialize/CoUninitialize. Достаточно это сделать один раз при запуске/завершении программы".
Поэтому вот пример с классом. Класс сам сделает эту задачу.

```
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib") //extern


//Управление звуком
class VolumeOS
{
public:
    HRESULT hr;
    bool decibels;
    bool scalar;
    double Volume;

    VolumeOS()
    {
        hr=NULL;
        decibels = false;
        scalar = false;
        CoInitialize(NULL);
        //newVolume=nVolume;
    }



    bool VolumeSET(double nVolume,bool bScalar)
    {
        double newVolume = nVolume;
        Volume = newVolume;
        IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                              __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator);
        IMMDevice *defaultDevice = NULL;

        hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice);
        deviceEnumerator->Release();
        deviceEnumerator = NULL;

        IAudioEndpointVolume *endpointVolume = NULL;
        hr = defaultDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), 
             CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, (LPVOID *)&endpointVolume);
        defaultDevice->Release();
        defaultDevice = NULL;

        // -------------------------
        float currentVolume = 0;
        endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevel(&currentVolume);
        //printf("Current volume in dB is: %f\n", currentVolume);

        hr = endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&currentVolume);
        //CString strCur=L"";
        //strCur.Format(L"%f",currentVolume);
        //AfxMessageBox(strCur);

        // printf("Current volume as a scalar is: %f\n", currentVolume);
        if (bScalar==false)
        {
            hr = endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevel((float)newVolume, NULL);
        }
        else if (bScalar==true)
        {
            hr = endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar((float)newVolume, NULL);
        }
        endpointVolume->Release();



        return FALSE;
    }


    ~VolumeOS()
    {
        CoUninitialize();
    }       
};


float i = 0;
int main()
{
    VolumeOS A;

    float volume = 0;

    while(1)
    {
    i+=0.01;
    volume = (sin(i)+1)/2;

    A.VolumeSET(volume,true);
    std::cout<<volume<<std::endl;
    Sleep(33);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не нужно каждый раз вызывать CoInitialize/CoUninitialize. Достаточно это сделать один раз при запуске/завершении программы.